# Extract sheet from many excel workbooks based on sheet title

Tags: python, excel, pandas, database, extract

I need to extract a specific sheet from many Excel workbooks. The sheet is titled exactly the same way in each Excel workbook.

After extraction, I need to name each data frame (created from each extracted sheet) based on the beginning of the title of the corresponding Excel workbook.
**Example**: For a sheet titled '*Pizza*' (same for every Excel workbook), and an Excel workbook titled '*Coke_2021*', the data frame should be automatically named '*Pizza_Coke*'.
The format of the Excel workbooks is: '*Coke_2021*', '*Sprite_2019*', etc., so it is very predictable.

I have the following code, but am stuck on Step 1 (extracting sheets).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import pyodbc
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
import itertools
import ntpath
import calendar

## UI - Asking user for their input and output files
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.databases =  filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir = "C:/",title = "Select the location of your Soda files (you may select multiple files)", filetypes = (("Excel Files","*.xlsx"),("all files","*.*")))
db_list = root.tk.splitlist(root.databases)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Label each data frame"?

Comment: If your problem is the first step, why is this tagged with "tkinter"? It doesn't look like tkinter has anything to do with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by naming each dataframe, but we can load the dataframes and generate the desired name.

Pandas is super helpful when reading Excel and CSV files.
The `pandas.read_excel()` function can read in a specific Excel sheet to a dataframe, and it can also read in all sheets as a dictionary of dataframes. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_excel for details.

The below code loads the "Pizza" sheet from a list of Excel files and stores them as a dictionary of `dataframes` with the "sheet_file" naming.

```py
import pandas as pd

sheet_name = 'Pizza'
xl_files = ['Coke_2021.xlsx', 'Sprite_2019.xlsx']

dataframes = {}
for xl_file in xl_files:
    # create new name with sheet name & first part of file name
    name = f'{sheet_name}_{xl_file.split("_")[0]}'
    dataframes[name] = pd.read_excel(xl_file, sheet_name=sheet_name)

# now can access a given dataframe by the "sheet_file" naming
# could also easily export to Excel with the new name like below
dataframes['Pizza_Coke'].to_excel('Pizza_Coke.xlsx')
```

Above, we assume that you have the Excel file names available like assigned to `xl_files`.  From your code, it looks like there may be a list of the Excel files stored in `db_list` that use absolute paths.  In that case, we would need to modify the name-creation code a bit to just use the file name instead of the entire path.  Something like this should help there:

```py
import os

dataframes = {}
for xl_file in db_list:
    filename = os.path.basename(xl_file)  # use this in next line!
    name = f'{sheet_name}_{filename.split("_")[0]}'
    dataframes[name] = pd.read_excel(xl_file, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

If instead you want to load many sheets from one Excel file, the below code generates the same sort of result.

```py
import pandas as pd

xl_file = 'Coke_2021.xlsx'

# load the Excel file's sheets into a dictionary
# of form: {sheet_name: sheet_dataframe, ...}
dataframes = pd.read_excel(xl_file, None)

renamed_dataframes = {}
for sheet_name, df in dataframes.items():
    new_name = f'{sheet_name}_{xl_file.split("_")[0]}'
    renamed_dataframes[new_name] = df

renamed_dataframes['Pizza_Coke'].to_excel('Pizza_Coke.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried what you suggested, but it didn't quite work. Since I'm importing many Excel workbooks at once, on the order of 30, I can't name them specifically within the code. For the piece of code in the first section you wrote ```xl_files = ['Coke_2021.xlsx', 'Sprite_2019.xlsx']``` I believe this would have to reference that imported list of workbooks, but when I referenced db_list (within my code example), it didn't work. Not sure where the issue is

Comment: @Sam I added an example to help with using `db_list`.